# Where Does One Find Logs of Pentesting Tools on Windows

Tags: windows-8, security, windows-8.1, logging, event-viewer

I'm scanning my Windows 8 machine with Nmap and OpenVAS (from a different machine on my LAN and another one over WAN) and I'm looking for logs for the occurrence of such events in the Event Viewer but there isn't anything about anyone scanning me.

How do I find logs in Windows to rule out that someone might be scanning my machine (or network) in an unauthorized manner.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [Intrusion Detection System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) such as [Snort](https://www.snort.org/).  Intrusion Detection Systems generally run in the background, or on separate machines strategically placed on a network (often on a SPAN port in enterprise networks, but it isn't absolutely necessary) such that they can monitor all traffic coming in and out and, on the fly, check it based on predefined rules (which you, the admin, get to do...don't worry, there are plenty of examples floating around to do basic things though!).  Then, depending on what options you've configured, as well as what particular IDS software you've chosen, it will do one or several of a few things:

1. Log the packet(s) to a file, generally along with a timestamp, as well as which rule got it flagged
2. Block/drop/screen the packet (this honestly is more the scope of an Intrusion Prevention System, but the lines get blurry sometimes)
3. Pipe the file through a separate filter, such as a system like fail2ban, which bans users IP addresses based on matching certain activity.

Comment: Valuble information! Thank you very much. I'll be checking Snort and if it has what I need, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to answer my own question (I assume it's ok since there's an option for it).

I used **Wireshark** on Windows to accomplish that. I google'd and found that logs can't be obtained for such purpose.

So, for anyone interested, get Wireshark and start the scan, you can see it in the capture log. But I'd assume one will have to have Wireshark running 24/7 in case of public facing services like Windows servers. I don't know any better options but this will do well for my purpose.

Comment: Wireshark will work, but IDS systems use the same basis as wireshark, along with rule matching, and are generally optimized for running in the background, whereas Wireshark is more of a diagnostic tool.  See my answer for more explanation.  As for answering your own question: not only is it allowed, it's encouraged! If you have trouble, don't get help, and figure it out on your own, offering up the explanation for how you did it serves to both help others who run into your same issue, as provide you with a public posting explaining your issue should you need it again.